# Set default access permissions on a folder created in a custom installer

Tags: windows-installer, custom-action

I have created a simple custom installer as described [here](http://raquila.com/software/configure-app-config-application-settings-during-msi-install/). My new installer works as expected. It creates a folder and adds the path into the app.config file.

The problem is that the read-only flag on the folder gets set and the write permissions for non admin users are removed.

If I manually create the folder and set the permissions, they get reset when the installer is run.

How can I specify these parameters from within my custom installer?

**EDIT:**

I use the code shown below to set the security permissions for everyone and this is working fine.

```
// Get the directory info for the existing folder
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(settingsFileDir);

// Now apply user access permissions to the folder
if (dirInfo != null)
{
    DirectorySecurity security = dirInfo.GetAccessControl();
    security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
    security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
    dirInfo.SetAccessControl(security);
}
```

When I try to set the folder attributes to remove the read only setting no change is made. I do this with:

```
dirInfo.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the code below does actually set the access permissions of the folder.

```
// Get the directory info for the existing folder
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(settingsFileDir);

// Now apply user access permissions to the folder
if (dirInfo != null)
{
    DirectorySecurity security = dirInfo.GetAccessControl();
    security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
    security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
    dirInfo.SetAccessControl(security);
}
```

If you view the properties of the folder you can see that the readonly attribute appears to be set but does allow files to be written.

[image: Test Folder Properties]

Answer (score 1):

To modify permissions you can try using [XCACLS.EXE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318754) as a [custom action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?ppud=4).

To change the read-only attribute you can use a custom action with custom code. Here is an article which may help: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/10/19/how-can-i-change-a-read-only-file-to-a-read-write-file.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure using an external application is the best way forward. It would require it to be shipped with my app and it appears may not work with newer OS's.

Comment: What tool are you using to create the MSI?

Comment: Visual Studio 2008. I have created a custom action installer class for applying a file path into the app.config file and then move any existing files to this folder.

Comment: Visual Studio setup projects do not support folder permissions. So you need a custom action or another setup authoring tool. Also, it's not a good idea to move installed files during install.